# Как вернуть скролл на изначальную позицию после повторного нажатия на тот же класс?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Набросал простенький код. При нажатии на .js-o-card срабатывает прокрутка к блоку с классом .active-card. Как мне сделать возвращение скролла на изначальную позицию? Знаю, что нужно записывать текущею позицию скролла, но не знаю как это реализовать кодом...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.js-o-card').click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('active-card');
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $(".active-card .thumbnail").offset().top - $(window).height()/3}, 1000);
  });
});
```

UPD 07-08 8-52
Изменил код, но в исходное состояние не возвращает. Остальное работает. Подскажите, что я делаю не так?

```
$('.js-o-card').on('click', function () {
    var $window = $(window);
    if (!$(this).hasClass('active-card')) {
        
        $(this).addClass('active-card');
        
        console.log('первый однако');
        
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(".active-card .thumbnail").offset().top - $(window).height() / 3
        }, 1000);

        $window.scroll(function () {

            localStorage.setItem('scrollPosition', $window.scrollTop())
        })

    } else {
        $(this).removeClass('active-card');
        
        console.log('второй однако');
        
        window.scroll(0, localStorage.getItem('scrollPosition') | 0)
    }
});
```

UPD 07-08-21 16-32

```
var scrollPosition = null;

$('.js-o-card').on('click', function () {
    var $window = $(window);
    if (!$(this).hasClass('active-card')) {
        
        $(this).addClass('active-card');
        
        console.log('первый однако');
        
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(".active-card .thumbnail").offset().top - $(window).height() / 3
        }, 1000);

        $window.scroll(function () {
            scrollPosition = $window.scrollTop();
        })

    } else {
        if (scrollPosition) {
            window.scrollTo(0, scrollPosition);
            scrollPosition = null;
        }
        
        $(this).removeClass('active-card');
        
        console.log('второй однако');
    
    }
});
```

Comment: _Как мне сделать возвращение скролла на изначальную позицию?_ - перед скроллом запомнить текущую позицию

Comment: @InDevX сделал так, но не робит возвращение в исходное состояние при втором клике по тому же элементу.

Comment: Не так... Во-первых, сохранять в переменную (`let scrollPosition = null;`), во-вторых, алгоритм: проверяем пустая ли переменная (`if (scrollPosition) {...`) - если да - сохраняем в неё позицию, если нет - делаем скролл до сохранённой позиции и обнуляем переменную (`scrollPosition = null`)

Comment: @InDevX Я сделал запись позиции в переменную, но функция scrollTo() ничего не делает, а если посмотреть лог, то там нет ошибок. В чём может быть проблема? Я обновил код на CodePen io

Comment: @InDevX Точнее код обновил не на CodePen, а в этом вопросе.

Comment: Написал ведь что не так... Вы сейчас при скролле всё время перезаписываете переменную - это вообще ни к чему... Добавьте воспроизводимый пример

Comment: @InDevX спасибо!